# Mailgun Environment run on testmode if not in production in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

these are the config setting i am using and i just want to enable mailgun to run on testmode if it is not in production. any help appreciated.

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('SUPPORT', 'hello@example.com'),  
    'name' => env('NAME', 'Example'),
],
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('PASSWORD'),
```

Comment: If "what" not in production? It is unclear. Do you want to run the mailgun in test mode if the application is not in production mode?

Comment: yes basic idea is like when i am not in production i want to run mailgun on testmode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary to set the values

```
'key' => $app->environment()=='production' ? 'prod_mode' : 'test_mode'
```